# format the different types of date in CSV using python 2.6

Tags: python, csv, python-2.6

I have formatted my csv file and now it looks like this:

```
100|1000|newyork|2015/10/04|2015/10/04 16:23:37.040000|

101|1001|london|2015/10/04|2015/10/04 16:23:37.040000|

102|1002|california|2015/10/04|2015/10/04 16:23:37.041000|

103|1003|Delhi|2015/10/04|2015/10/04 16:23:37.041000|

104|1004|Mumbai|2015/10/04|2015/10/04 16:23:37.041000|

105|1005|Islamabad|2015/10/04|2015/10/04 16:23:37.041000|

106|1006|karachi|2015/10/04|2015/10/04 16:23:37.041000|
```

Now I have two different format of dates which I want to convert it into 'YYmmdd' format.

Can any one suggest best way to achieve this.
Note: The file name should not get change and for your reference this is how I am achieveing the formatted file which is given here:

```
inputfile = 'c:\Working\HK.txt'

outputfile = inputfile + '.tmp'
with contextlib.nested(open(inputfile, 'rb'), open(outputfile, 'wb')) as (inf,outf):
    reader = csv.reader(inf)
    writer = csv.writer(outf, delimiter='|')
    for row in reader:
        writer.writerow([col.replace('|', ' ') for col in row])
        writer.writerow([])
os.remove(inputfile)
os.rename(outputfile,inputfile)
```

Comment: so why not format it as wanted in the first way with the correct format pattern: `%y%m%d`?

Comment: @Daniel I am getting this date from other system which is having this format and I can't do which is not in my hand. So looking for something which we can. :)

Comment: If your reading in from a file and building a CSV I would fix it there.   If you know the structure  just use use parse and strftime('%Y%m%d') on the date columns.

Comment: ya, I am reading it from csv file and then formatting it , since new to python so may be i will ask silly question if i get hint it will be good so that I can also try from my end, it always better to try rather than asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work. You can tweak the date format anyway you like by changing the strftime.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from dateutil.parser import parse

lines = ['100|1000|newyork|2015/10/04|2015/10/04 16:23:37.040000|',
         '101|1001|london|2015/10/04|2015/10/04 16:23:37.040000|',
         '102|1002|california|2015/10/04|2015/10/04 16:23:37.041000|',
         '103|1003|Delhi|2015/10/04|2015/10/04 16:23:37.041000|',
         '104|1004|Mumbai|2015/10/04|2015/10/04 16:23:37.041000|',
         '105|1005|Islamabad|2015/10/04|2015/10/04 16:23:37.041000|',
         '106|1006|karachi|2015/10/04|2015/10/04 16:23:37.041000|']

for line in lines:
    parts = line.split("|");

    tmp_date = parse(parts[3])
    parts[3] = tmp_date.strftime('%Y%m%d') 

    tmp_date = parse(parts[4])
    parts[4] = tmp_date.strftime('%Y%m%d')

    new_line = "|".join(parts) 
    print new_line
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have Python 2.6+ you could do it just in python

```
from __future__ import print_function
import re

with open('data','r') as f, open('data_out', 'w') as f_out:

    for line in f:
        line = re.sub('(|\d{4})/(\d{2})/(\d{2})',r'\1\3\2', line)
        line = re.sub('\s+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d+(|)',r'\1', line)

        print(line, file=f_out)

this is what i got in my data_out

100|1000|newyork|20151004|20151004|
101|1001|london|20151004|20151004|
102|1002|california|20151004|20151004|
103|1003|Delhi|20151004|20151004|
104|1004|Mumbai|20151004|20151004|
105|1005|Islamabad|20151004|20151004|
106|1006|karachi|20151004|20151004|
```

Comment: @cyborg try change print(line, file=f_out) to print >>f_out,line or to f_out.write(line)